# SELECT COUNT in cycle

Tags: mysql, count

I have two table: 'news' and 'comments'. How to count the number of comments of every news article?

```
SELECT `news`.`name`,`news`.`text` (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `comments` WHERE
 `comments`.`news_id`=`news`.`id`) AS `comments` FROM  `news`,`comments`
```

That doesn't work right.

Comment: Define "doesn't work right". Also, your outer select doesn't need `FROM comments`. Just  `... AS \`comments\` FROM \`news`.

Comment: You want to count number of comments corresponds to a news article?

Comment: while($row=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo $row[name].'<br>'.$row[comments].' comments';
}

Every news will have such number of comments as the first news has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way

```sql
SELECT n.name, n.text, COUNT(c.news_id) total_comments
  FROM news n LEFT JOIN comments c 
    ON n.id = c.news_id
 GROUP BY n.id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb568/1)** demo